# How to rotate only image, Not Imageview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview

I am capturing an image (in landscape mode) and sending to nextActivity imageview. While rotating the image, the entire imageview gets rotated along with image.

How to achieve only rotation of captured image, not whole imageview.
This is what i have tried

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivDocument"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="95dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:contentDescription=""
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_take_photo" />
```

while setting up - inside onActivityResult

```
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1000) {
        docImage = data!!.getStringExtra("imagePath")
        val fileUri = Uri.parse(docImage)
        ivDocument.setImageURI(fileUri)
        ivDocument.rotation = 270f

        }
```

Output - image gets rotated with imageview (which is a square frame)
Expected -  only image should rotated not imageview

Can someone help me if it is possible

Comment: i have same issue &  resolved it

Comment: yes, I have also done it

Comment: What happen...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use image Matrix to do it:

```
val matrix = Matrix()
matrix.reset()
matrix.postRotate(270f)
ivDocument.setImageMatrix(matrix)
```

Comment: You just need to replace `ivDocument.rotation = 270f` by my codes. Setting image using uri doesn't need to change